# AGM map display full address on click or hover to marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, google-maps

I displayed multiple markers on the AGM map using latitudes and longitudes. I want to display full address on each marker. Can anybody help me to display full address on click or hover to each marker?

I have used below example to display map using Angular.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-google-maps-demo?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Any luck with achieving the full address behavior using any Google API to fetch address based on latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is my solution for the normal InfoWindow, but it should work with SnazzyWindow as well:

**.html**

<agm-map>
  <agm-marker *ngFor="let marker of markers" 
    (markerClick)="openWindow(marker.id)" 
    [latitude]="marker.lat" 
    [longitude]="marker.lng">
    <agm-info-window 
      [isOpen]="isInfoWindowOpen(marker.id)"
      [latitude]="marker.lat" 
      [longitude]="marker.lng">InfoWindow #{{marker.id}}</agm-info-window>
  </agm-marker>
</agm-map>

<button type="button" (click)="openWindow(5)">Open InfoWindow 5</button>

**.ts**

openedWindow : number = 0; // alternative: array of numbers

openWindow(id) {
    this.openedWindow = id; // alternative: push to array of numbers
}

isInfoWindowOpen(id) {
    return this.openedWindow == id; // alternative: check if id is in array
}


Make sure you added the latitude and longitude attributes to <agm-marker> and <agm-info-window>. Otherwise the <agm-info-window> position would differ from the marker, when you open it by the button.

If you want to have multiple info windows open at the same time, have a look at the comments above, starting with alternative:.

You may need to add more attributes to make it work. The code is limited to explain the basic functionality.
```